# New MediaTemple site displays '404 File Not Found - nginx' message

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, configuration-files, mediatemple

I just set up a new new domain and uploaded some simple static html files & assets.  The images do not display and when I try to pull one up directly in the browser I get a page that reads

`404 File Not Found - nginx`

This is weird because although I know media temple uses nginx to run the VMs, the websites are always served up with apache...

Anyway, what led up to this was that I:

1. created a new webspace
2. created a new domain within that webspace
3. uploaded a new image (logo.jpg)
4. found that logo.jpg would not load and leads to the 404 described above

After creating the new domain, I got an automated message shown below (with specific info removed):

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: [user] [email]
Date: Thu, Jan 30, 2014 at 12:40 PM
Subject: Unable to configure a web server on the host [domain]
To: [me]

Unable to generate the web server configuration file on the host [domain] because of the following errors:

nginx: [emerg] listen() to [ip address]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Please resolve the errors in web server configuration templates and generate the file again.
```

What is the issue here?  It's a brand new site - it shouldn't be giving me this kind of grief..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have no idea what upset nginx, but the nginx configuration file needed to be refreshed. This was accomplished with the following ssh commands:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/nginxmng --disable
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/nginxmng --enable
```